# Android. Access dialog's parent variables

Tags: android

From my activity I call `showDialog(0)` and then in the switch of the method `onCreateDialog` I would like to access a variable from the parent activity. It doesn't seem to work though. I've tried

```
this.neededVariable
```

or

```
((MyActivity)dialog.getOwnerActivity()).neededVariable
```

but they don't seem to work. Any ideas? It might be something simple which I'm not getting cause I'm very tired :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the value of that variable to your dialog in `setArgumenet`, or you can use `Fragment Callback` to communicate the `Activity`, [here is the example of callback](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you are in dialog you should use dialog context to interact with your dialog and when you want your Activity context you can use your activity name like :

```
YourActivityName.this
```

here is a sample that i've used in dialog code to access a TextView inside of the parent activity :

```
((TextView)DayReportActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.edtDailyCPCode)).setText(CPCodeText);
```